# pyqt | gui generated by object wont show

Tags: python, pyqt

a quick description of my "program". When I click the menu entry in the main window, a popup window opens to get the user input, triggering a subframe to show in the main window (which was hidden until then). This subframe has a button which should create another frame (part of another class) imbedded in the subframe. The Problem is that it won't show up when I click the button. I've searched for a solution, but couldn't find one.
Thanks in advance!

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.uic import *

class Main_fr(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mainwin = loadUi("Main.ui", self)
        self.menu_crnewwin.triggered.connect(self.inputwindow)

        self.subWin = loadUi("subwin_Fr.ui", self.mainwin.mainFrame)
        self.subWin.createObj.clicked.connect(self.obj_fr)

        self.subWin.hide()
        self.mainwin.show()


    def inputwindow(self):
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Input Window", "Some input:")
        if ok:
            self.subWin_fr()


    def subWin_fr(self):
        self.subWin.show()

    def obj_fr(self):
        self.w = Some_obj(self.subWin.objframe, "userentry").gui()



class Some_obj():
    def __init__(self, master, userinput):
        self.master = master
        self.userinput = userinput
        self.iterable = loadUi("subsubWin.ui", self.master)
        self.iterable.hide()


    def gui(self):
        self.iterable.show()


def run():    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Main_fr()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Main file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>df</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="df">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>584</width>
    <height>578</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Fruchtfolge</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="mainFrame"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>584</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="menu_crnewwin"/>
    <addaction name="open"/>
    <addaction name="close"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="close_prog"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="toolBar">
   <property name="windowTitle">
    <string>toolBar</string>
   </property>
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <action name="menu_crnewwin">
   <property name="text">
    <string>New</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="open">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="close">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Close</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="close_prog">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Close program</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

subwin file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>761</width>
    <height>413</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
   <item row="3" column="0" colspan="2">
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_3">
         <property name="text">
          <string>option 1</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string>option 2</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
       <property name="text">
        <string>option 3</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item row="0" column="0" colspan="2">
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="text">
        <string>some text</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item row="1" column="0" colspan="2">
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="createObj">
       <property name="text">
        <string>new object</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item row="2" column="0" colspan="2">
    <widget class="QWidget" name="objframe" native="true">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_5"/>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

subsubwin file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>746</width>
    <height>48</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
   <property name="spacing">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <property name="horizontalSpacing">
      <number>0</number>
     </property>
     <item row="0" column="23">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_28" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="25">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_25" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="35">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_13" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="4">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_2" native="true">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="layoutDirection">
        <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="33">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_18" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="28">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_15" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="name">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Name:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="36">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_23" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="27">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_26" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="21">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_27" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="20">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_10" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="8">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_8" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="37">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_17" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="14">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_21" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="22">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_11" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="13">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_9" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="32">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_20" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="31">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_19" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="19">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_24" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="9">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_32" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="16">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_30" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="24">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_12" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
       <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
        <enum>QComboBox::AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow</enum>
       </property>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>some list</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="18">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_29" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="6">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_5" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="11">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_31" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="15">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_34" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="30">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_16" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="17">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_14" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="5">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_4" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="26">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_7" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="12">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_33" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="34">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_3" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="7">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_6" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="3">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_36" native="true"/>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="38">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="10">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_35" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="29">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_22" native="true">
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string>background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_37" native="true"/>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: share the .ui...

Comment: the .ui file is an XML so open it with any editor, copy it and add it to your question.

Comment: ty for the hint! I've updated my post

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are trying to replace one widget with another and that is not possible since changing the reference does not change the object, the solution in this case is to place the new widget inside `objframe` using the layout that you have set in Qt Designer:

```
class Main_fr(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def obj_fr(self):
        self.w = Some_obj(self.subWin.objframe, "userentry")
        self.w.gui()

class Some_obj():
    def __init__(self, master, userinput):
        self.master = master
        self.userinput = userinput
        self.iterable = loadUi("subsubWin.ui")
        self.master.layout().addWidget(self.iterable)

    def gui(self):
        self.iterable.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense now. My thought was, that it would just insert it into the master widget. Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: @Sneakybeaver If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that's the best way to thank :-)